Can I be eligible to receive retirement benefits if I started working at age 62?
I started working in January 2019 at age 62 and finished working in December 2028. Are 10 full years of work considered?
key information from the comments:
Request Late retirement monthly benefits in USA after 70 years old Is considered 1 year complete of 365 days if I will reach 70 years old that year in 353 days, because I will complete 10 years working 12 days before the end of the year 2028

What benefits are you asking about? Considered for what? What country are you in?

And whatever country you're asking about, the situation may have changed in four year's time.

Request Late retirement monthly benefits in USA after 70 years old
Is considered 1 year complete of 365 days if I will reach 70 years old that year in 353 days, because I will complete 10 years working 12 days before the end of the year 2028

You commented about the US requirements, so I'm assuming you're asking about the US Social Security retirement benefits.
The eligibility for the US SS retirement benefits is 40 credits. Each credit used to mean a quarter of paying the FICA taxes, i.e.: 40 quarters of work.
This is no longer so. You still need the 40 credits, but credits accrue on annual basis based on the income you've earned (subject to FICA taxes). You can accrue up to 4 credits per year, for each $1730 you earn. I.e.: you need to earn $6920 a year, each year for 10 years, to become eligible even if you only worked 1 day in each of these years. Amounts are adjusted for inflation each year.
The benefits amounts are calculated based on the highest 35 years of earnings. If you only worked 10 years - then the rest of the years will be considered as $0 earned.
See the SSA booklet for more details.
